# Pass get variable to php through ajax post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have 3 files: my main page chatterFront.php, then my js ajax file chatterScript.js and the php script that gets and sends the messages chatterEngine.php. How can I define a variable and pass it from chatterFront.php to chatterEngine.php. I cannot change the ajax post methods. I also would like it to be secure (server side).

Basically its a $_GET variable I want to pass from chatterFront.php?CID=1 into the chatterEngine.php. Is it something to do with global variables?

I want to use the variable both in the sending and retrieving of messages

chatterFront.php (The front html of the chat)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Chatting System</title>
<link href="chatterStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="chatterScript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<ul id="chatMessageList" class="chatMessageList"></ul>

<form action="chatterEngine.php" method="post" id="formPostChat">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="text" id="postCID" name="postCID" value="1">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <input type="text" id="postText">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <input type="submit" value="Reply" />
        <span class="errorMessage" id="postError"></span>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

chatterEngine.php (The php file that ajax calls)

```
<?php
    class Chatter{
        //change this according to your database setup
        protected $server = 'localhost';
        protected $username = 'hidden';
        protected $password = 'hidden';
        protected $database = 'hidden';
        //leave this as our database connection later
        protected $connection = null;

        public function __construct(){
            $this->connection = @mysql_connect($this->server, $this->username, $this->password);
            if($this->connection){
                if(!mysql_select_db($this->database)) die('database not found');
            }
            else die('database connection failed. Check your setup');

            $mode = $this->fetch('mode');

            switch($mode){
                case 'get':
                    $this->getMessage();
                    break;
                case 'post':
                    $this->postMessage();
                    break;
                default:
                    $this->output(false, 'Wrong mode.');
                    break;
            }

            return;
        }

        protected function getMessage(){
            $endtime = time() + 20;
            $lasttime = $this->fetch('lastTime');
            $postCID = ; // Set this variable in chatterFront.php
            $curtime = null;

            while(time() <= $endtime){
                $rs = mysql_query("
                    SELECT *
                    FROM conversation_reply
                    WHERE c_id_fk = $postCID
                    ORDER BY time desc
                    LIMIT 0, 30
                ");

                if($rs){
                    $messages = array();

                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
                        $messages[] = array(
                            'user' => $row['user_id_fk'],
                            'text' => $row['reply'],
                            'time' => $row['time']
                        );
                    }

                    $curtime = strtotime($messages[0]['time']);
                }

                if(!empty($messages) && $curtime != $lasttime){
                    $this->output(true, '', array_reverse($messages), $curtime);
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    sleep(1);
                }
            }
        }

        protected function postMessage(){
            $user = $this->fetch('user');
            $text = $this->fetch('text');

            if(empty($text)){
                $this->output(false, 'Username and Chat Text must be inputted.');
            }
            else{
                $userid = 1;
                $conversationid = 1;
                $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];              
                $rs = mysql_query("
                    INSERT INTO conversation_reply(                     
                        reply,
                        user_id_fk,
                        ip,
                        time,
                        c_id_fk
                    )
                    VALUES(
                        '$text',
                        '$user',
                        '$ip',
                        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                        '$conversationid'
                    )
                ");

                if($rs){
                    $this->output(true, '');
                }
                else{
                    $this->output(false, 'Chat posting failed. Please try again.');
                }
            }
        }

        protected function fetch($name){
            $val = isset($_POST[$name]) ? $_POST[$name] : '';
            return mysql_real_escape_string($val, $this->connection);
        }

        protected function output($result, $output, $message = null, $latest = null){
            echo json_encode(array(
                'result' => $result,
                'message' => $message,
                'output' => $output,
                'latest' => $latest
            ));
        }
    }

    new Chatter();
```

chatterScript.js (The ajax)

```
    function Chatter(){
    this.getMessage = function(callback, lastTime){
        var t = this;
        var latest = null;

        $.ajax({
            'url': 'chatterEngine.php',
            'type': 'post',
            'dataType': 'json',
            'data': {
                'mode': 'get',
                'lastTime': lastTime,
            },
            'timeout': 30000,
            'cache': false,
            'success': function(result){
                if(result.result){
                    callback(result.message);
                    latest = result.latest;
                }   
            },
            'error': function(e){
                console.log(e);
            },
            'complete': function(){
                t.getMessage(callback, latest);
            }
        });
    };

    this.postMessage = function(user, text, callback){
        $.ajax({
            'url': 'chatterEngine.php',
            'type': 'post',
            'dataType': 'json',
            'data': {
                'mode': 'post',
                'user': user,
                'text': text
            },
            'success': function(result){
                callback(result);
            },
            'error': function(e){
                console.log(e);
            }
        });
    };
};

var c = new Chatter();

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#formPostChat').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var user = $('#postUsername');
        var text = $('#postText');
        var err = $('#postError');

        c.postMessage(user.val(), text.val(), function(result){
            if(result){
                text.val('');
            }
            err.html(result.output);
        });

        return false;
    });

    c.getMessage(function(message){
        var chat = $('#chatMessageList').empty();

        for(var i = 0; i < message.length; i++){
            chat.append(
                '<li class="chatMessage">' +
                '       <span class="chatUsername">' + message[i].user + '</span>' +
                '       <p class="chatText">' + message[i].text + '</p>' +
                '</li>'
            );
        }

        $('#chatMessageList').scrollTop($('#chatMessageList')[0].scrollHeight);
    });
});
```

I have all the database set up and I did get it working using session variables and that worked but extremely slow (for some reason - possibly because of where I put them - may have caused loops)

Comment: I would stick with the session method that you went with previously. This is only going to clutter the landscape and if you can't modify the ajax functions (such as, to expect a URL), then this will be a huge headache.

Comment: the session variable way actually created loops or something I don't know how id implement it

Comment: The session doesn't create the loops, the programmer does. :). Can we see the session code that you had working but was **slow**?

Comment: I added a session start to both php files at the very beginning and set $_SESSION['CID'] = $_GET['CID'] in chatterFront.php and inside of 'protected function getMessage(){' in chatterEngine.php i made $postCID = $_SESSION['CID']

Comment: Perfect! No reason that should be any slower than a $_GET['CID'] on the URL, plus it's cleaner. So the loop is likely due to the fact that code *later* on which is looping is slower, not necessarily the usage of $_SESSION. ;)

Comment: Sometimes it just breaks completely and i do not want to use that method since its to slow. will it be to do with where i put session_start(); ?

Comment: Wherever you initiate the session provides you with access to the session within the script.

Comment: can i not take it trough the ajax request